# How to reset the radio button icon to the default icon?

Tags: android

when I am developing an android app I changed the icon of the radio button. how to reset the radio button icon the default icon when the user clicks on reset button while the program is running ??

I want to do this without resetting the content view of the activity.

Comment: What did you do to change it in the first place? And may I ask as an aside, what you're trying to do? Are you interested in perhaps disabling or changing the radio button's behavior from a UX perspective?

Comment: my app is quiz app when the user submits the correct answer the icon of the radio button he checked will be changed to be an indicator that it's a correct answer.
and he can reset the quiz by clicking in button i want to reset the radio button icon to default when he clicks on this button

Comment: I have not tried this - so I'm not sure if it work, but you could get the `Drawable` object of the `RadioButton` before it is changed with   `Drawable d = yourRadioButton.getButtonDrawable();`  ... Now when you want to change it back to the original `Drawable` just use `yourRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(d);`

Comment: that's no working the app is crashed when trying this code

Comment: It sounds like a you have a pretty special use-case for that UX. You might be better off in terms of design and implementation to create your own sort of `View` for the RadioButtons instead of trying to override the existing `RadioButton` class. For instance, try creating your own `View` that incorporates a `TextView` and an `ImageView` as a list item in your app.

Comment: I only want to know if there is a way to reset the default icon of the radio button without resetting the content view of the activity or there is an alternative or not because making a custom view will not success in my app.
and thank you for helping

Answer (score -1):

You can undo your custom setting and return to the default using this method:

```
RadioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
```

Comment: This will remove the button circle instead of resetting it.